# How can "Ah! That's such a cop out because now I have to create a conversation." be rephrased? Is it ellipted?

Tags: meaning, ellipsis

I am not sure I understand what this means:

> I remember boys at school texting me asking me "How's things?". I just remember thinking, "***Ah! That's such a cop out because now I have to create a conversation."***

Is it ellipted? This line occurs at 05:55 in the Youtube video titled "*DO NOT say "how are you?"! Ask the question in a better way!*"

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is that you think might be ellipted, and why?

Comment: I would strongly advise you to give a link to the YouTube video in the future so we don't have to try to find it, and maybe click on the wrong one if there's another (if there aren't multiple already) down the line.

Comment: If you want to know what it means or what the grammatical structure is, then ask that, not how it can be rephrased. It's a straightforward sentence with a matrix clause "That's such a cop out" and a subordinate because-clause that runs to the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"Cop out," is an idiom for avoiding a task in a sneaky manner.

E.g., In the [Iliad](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Ejbailly/courses/clas21/notes/iliadnarrativebackground.html), when asked to judge whether Athena, Aphrodite or Hera was fairest, Paris could have said, "Oh, a mere mortal couldn't even appreciate such beauty," but that would have been a **cop-out** (and it would have cost him a bribe, too).